# how does cmpl $741354545, (%esi) work as a string compare for "1,0,"?

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, att

I was reading an asm program and the comments said:

```
# I check if the first 4 bytes of the string are "1,0,"
cmpl $741354545, (%esi)
jne printReset
```

Now, what I do understand is that the instructions checks if the first 4 bytes are `"1,0,"`  but what I don't get is how  `741354545` translates into `1,0,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's four BYTES, not BITS. (1 byte = 8 bits).

The 32 bit value `741354545` when split to separate bytes is (from least significant byte): 49, 44, 48, 44.

To verify I got it right, you can compose it back into 32 bit integer by 256<sup>0</sup>*49 + 256<sup>1</sup>*44 + 256<sup>2</sup>*48 + 256<sup>3</sup>*44 = 1*49 + 256*44 + 65536*48 + 16777216*44 = 741354545.

Or if you will check that value in hexadecimal formatting, the separate bytes are easier to see: `0x2C302C31` => `31 2C 30 2C`.

And that's what ASCII or UTF8 encoded string `"1,0,"` looks like when stored in memory. So when the memory contains such 4 bytes at the address `esi`, the ZF (zero flag) will be set (and other flags as defined by `sub`, as the `cmp` is basically "sub" instruction, discarding the result of subtraction, and keeping just the flags set). So the `jne` will jump to label `printReset` when some different string/garbage is stored in the memory at address `esi`.

Comment: Sorry, I misswrote bytes. Thank you a lot for explaining me this, have a nice day :)

Comment: @NicholasBejaoui if the answer works for you and you are satisfied, you can "accept it" by the mark on the left side I think, next to the top of the answer, which makes the question look "answered" in the feed, and stop people checking it further. (or if something is still confusing you, you can comment here to ask for some improvement in the answer)

Comment: Done ! Thank you and sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Sure, no problem, glad it did help. BTW from your question it looks like you should pay some more attention about how different informations are encoded in bits in the computer, what are common native types, and how they get stored in memory (like how the 4 characters stored as 4 consecutive bytes form also 32 bit integer value, if you interpret those 4 bytes as that ... as everything in assembly, you have only bit values, and everything else is "interpretation" encoded in the code which is using the values, the code may treat bit values in any way it wish, switching between chars/int easily).

Comment: probably the OP is more familiar with *octet* than *byte*, so he thinks it's *bites* and is the plural form of bit

Comment: @phuclv the plural form of "bit" is "bits", at least in x86 assembly world. But that's the problem, that value is 32 bits (not 4 bits). And 32 bits is 4 bytes (because one byte is group of eight bits, at least on x86 platforms, there do exist architectures where byte has different size, but they are somewhat more exotic, 8 bit byte is most common). That "i/y" (and correct numerical value) is important to be sure, which type of value one is dealing with. Would the OP use "32 bites" in comment, it would be sort of OK, just small typo, but "4 bites" is causing confusion.

Comment: phuclv's point was that this is probably a French translation issue, not a confusion between bits and bytes.  Everyone agrees that "bites" is wrong in English, but the French term the OP is used to is "octet" (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/byte).  Anyway yes, it's important to spell it byte, because "bite" is an English word unrelated to / unused in computing, but looks more like bit than byte to most readers.  (Even though it's only 1 letter away from either: delete or substitute, and is pronounced the same as byte.)